# How to get functions from express routes for unit testing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express

I have a JS controller with some routes exported.   I'd like to get at the functions used in the routes for unit testing.

Note I've seen a lot of blogs advocating creating real http requests to unit test express routes.   That's not exactly unit testing in my book.  It is more unit testing.

I want to call the functions directly in my tests, thus leaving (most of) the framework out of the test.

For instance:

controller.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

function foo(req, res) { ... }
function bar(req, res) { ... }

router.route("/api/foo").get(foo);

router.route("/api/bar").post(bodyParser, bar);

module.exports = router;
```

In my unit test, I'd like to call `foo(res, res)` directly (I'll make some mock req and res objects)

Comment: If you want to do undocumented things with Express routes, then go look at the Express source code and see if you can get access to the way routes are stored.  It's open source - the code is all available to you.  It sounds like you're asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: Of course if some routes require access to other Express things like sessions and/or various req or res methods or rely on middleware, then you've got a lot of mocking to do (essentially recreating a bunch of what Express does for you).  This seems like a fools errand to try to test a route handler alone.  You're assuming it works in isolation and is not part of a system of code (particularly middleware).

Comment: @jfriend00 not really a lot of mocking, it at least in my cases.   Just maybe headers and res methods.   Anyway, in other languages, a lot of mocking is considered **good practice**, because the test knows and tests for every single call made to external/injected objects.   Like Mockito in java - every call and every parameter is accounted for.   How any I doing anything that is undocumented?

Comment: Why the negative votes?

Comment: Replacing actual code (like middleware) with mocked code ends up testing the mocked code, not the real code.  So, you have to then account for testing that code too and at some point, you have to test everything together to see that it all works together.  I would think that testing an actual HTTP request would be more meaningful than just testing one function involved in creating the HTTP request.  You can certainly test smaller components than the actual HTTP request, but you can't skip testing the actual HTTP request.

Comment: @jfriend00  It ends up testing the interaction between your code and the mocked code.   I guess this is less meaningful than in a language that has contracts.   But still I think this is meaningful and more of a unit test than going through the framework.   Maybe this is my java bias showing.   In the java world, any test making actually http calls would not be considered a unit test.   Mocking is pretty easy and does show right away if the code has changed with respect to what the tests are mocking for.

Comment: I have no problem with a unit test that tests just a single function, but it is not a replacement for testing the actual HTTP request because that's the actual functional unit that is actually used and that can interact with lots of other parts of the system (particularly when middleware is being used or lots of methods on the req or res objects are being used).  Nobody is calling just the route handler by itself so you're just testing a piece of a component that is not used by itself. That's OK as long as you also test the whole component and test all the real code involved in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to do what you want is to add each function to the `module.exports`. That way you can require the controller into your test and call the functions directly.

```
// controller.js
module.exports = router;
module.exports._spec = {
  foo: foo,
  bar: bar
};


// controlerSpec.js
var app = require('controller');

app._spec.foo(mockReq, mockRes);
```

Comment: this is perfect, thanks.  I keep forgetting you can add anything you want to javascript entities.